# Chunk gives different answer than Knitr

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, chunks

Executing the R-markdown chunk 2 gives a different answer than is seen in the html output of knitr

I have tried stopping RStudio and restarting, I have tried to isolate the chunk so that no other code is affecting it.

### chunk 1

```
library(png);library(grid)
grid.raster(readPNG("figures/1.png"))
```

### chunk 2 example

```
# load data
library(kernlab)
data(spam)
set.seed(333)

# picking a small subset (10 values) from spam data set
smallSpam <- spam[sample(dim(spam)[1], size=10),]

plot(smallSpam$capitalAve,col=spamLabel)
```

In chunk 2 the 10th sample point has a `smallSpam$capitalAve` of about 2.44, in the R-Markdown generated html, the value is 16.

Why the difference between chunk and R-markdown html output?

Comment: `spamLabel` object is not defined in your code. Anyway, I can't reproduce your error with my environment: value is effectively 2.44 in my generated report. Do you knit with RStudio button or call `render`? Also, please add your `sessionInfo`.

Comment: You should also print `sessionInfo` in your document, to make sure you're using the same version of R in both.  The `sample()` function gives different results in 3.6.0 than in earlier versions.  I get 18 for `smallSpam$capitalAve[10]` in 3.6.0, and 2.444 in 3.4.2.

Comment: Thanks.  I believe the difference is due to the difference in R versions.  I will find the sessionInfo to confirm.  I also think I can reference the earlier version of the  kernlab package to generate the 2.44 value.  That value is part of an example from the Johns Hopkins Data Science MOOC.  Their example only makes sense if you can reproduce the 2.44 value.

Comment: sessioninfo:  > pander(sessionInfo())
**R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)**

**Platform:** x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit) 

**locale:**
_LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252_, _LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252_, _LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252_, _LC_NUMERIC=C_ and _LC_TIME=English_United States.1252_

**attached base packages:** 
_stats_, _graphics_, _grDevices_, _utils_, _datasets_, _methods_ and _base_

**other attached packages:** 
_pander(v.0.6.3)_ and _kernlab(v.0.9-27)_

**loaded via a namespace (and not attached):**

Comment: do you think I can reference the  3.4.2 version of kernlab to get the 2.44 value for the smallSpam$captialAve[10]  ?

Comment: It's not the package version, it's the RNG version within base R.  To get the old version, you can use `RNGversion("3.4.2")` in any later version of R.  Do be aware that this brings back bugs that were fixed in 3.6.0.

Comment: I put pander(sessionInfo()) into both the chunk and the bottom of the .Rmd  It shows that both have **R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)**, but the difference remains.  I'm going to try referencing R 3.4.2

Comment: This is solved! Thanks!  I used RNGversion("3.4.2")  in the chunk and both chunk and .Rmd now give the expected points.  BTW:  I put RNGversion("3.6.0") after the chunk in  question to have the  best  RNG going forward.  apologies for not-fully-reproducible-code & verbosity